# Conversão de DateInterval para int em PHP

Tags: php

Recebo o erro

> Notice: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int

na linha 78, onde fica o segundo `if`. O trecho do código faz parte de um `while`, nesse `Timeframe` é calculado quanto tempo desde a última postagem de um usuário em uma rede social. 
  Como posso resolver esse erro?

```
//Timeframe
        $date_time_row = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $start_date = new DateTime($date_time); //Time of post
        $end_date = new DateTime($date_time_row); //Current time
        $interval = $start_date->diff($end_date); //Difference between dates
        if($interval->y >= 1) {
            if($interval == 1)
                $time_message = $interval->y . " year ago"; //1 year ago
            else 
                $time_message = $interval->y . " years ago"; //1+ year ago

        }
```

Quando posto algo, o mesmo é repostado quando atualizo a página, mostrando um erro para cada postagem do usuário. Os posts são mostrados corretamente no final da página, mas o erro permanece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erro simples:

A variável `$interval` é um objeto e não um inteiro. Você está comparando duas coisas diferentes, o php tenta converter o objeto em um inteiro para fazer a comparação com o numero 1 mas não consegue.

Seguindo a sua lógica, acredito que o que você quer é:

```
if($interval->y == 1) // pegar a diferença de anos "y" e ver se é igual a 1
```

Se o `$interval` fosse uma string numérica ou um boolean true:

```
$interval = true;
if($interval == 1)
```

Ele passaria pelo `if` sem problema algum.

Comment: Usei `$interval = true;
if($interval == 1)`e recebo o erro: Trying to get property 'y' of non-object, o mesmo para meses, dias e horas.

Comment: @AndréCavalcante sim... Mas não é para vc fazer isso. Isso foi apenas para mostrar que o php, faz essa conversão naturalmente. Use o primeiro exemplo do if que eu te mostrei.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esta dúvida pode ser facilmente resolvida.
Nesse trecho de código você esta utilizando o objeto `interval` para comparar com um interio.

```
if($interval->y >= 1) {
    if($interval == 1)
        $time_message = $interval->y . " year ago"; //1 year ago
    else 
        $time_message = $interval->y . " years ago"; //1+ year 
}
```

Para resolver você deve compara o atributo `y` de `interval` com o 1 da seguinte maneira:

```
if($interval->y >= 1) {
    if($interval->y == 1)
        $time_message = $interval->y . " year ago"; //1 year ago
    else 
        $time_message = $interval->y . " years ago"; //1+ year 
}
```

Mas você ainda pode simplificar a operação usando um operador ternário:

```
if($interval->y >= 1) {
    $time_message = ($interval->y == 1) ? $interval->y." year ago" :$interval->y . " years ago";
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!